# Possible to fill SqlDataSource with SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I currently have this code to populate ASP.NET gridview from code behind with DataTable.

```
 protected void bindGridView()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id AS 'Member ID', name AS Name, age AS Age, sympton AS Sympton, phone AS Phone, nirc AS NIRC, address AS Address FROM tbl_customer_profile WHERE id = @id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtSearchID.Text);
        DataTable dtSearchResult = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter daSearchResult = new SqlDataAdapter();

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            daSearchResult.SelectCommand = cmd;
            daSearchResult.Fill(dtSearchResult);
            gridSearchResult.DataSource = dtSearchResult;
            gridSearchResult.DataBind();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

But I would lose the Grid's Selection, Sorting, Paging functions. So I was thinking if I could fill to SqlDataSource instead of Datatable and then bind to Gridview, I wouldn't have to handle the selection, sorting etc manually?

But I can't just simply do like daSearchResult.Fill(sqlDataSource1);

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like what Neeraj was saying you can bind directly to a gridview with an SqlDataSource.
You don't need to have all that plumbing code.

This is how in asp.net

```
      <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="source"></asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="source" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is how in C#

```
        SqlDataSource source =new SqlDataSource();
        GridView grid = new GridView();

        grid.DataSource = s;
        grid.DataBind();
```